# How to render image from the URL in tkinter python3

Tags: tkinter, mapreduce, bigdata, python-3.6

I used Tkinter to display the image from the URL but getting much error regarding URL input is too long.

I tried using different packages and combination of codes but still getting different outputs.

```
URL = article.top_image

u = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()

b64_data = base64.encodestring(raw_data)
root = tk.Tk()
# The image (but in the label widget)
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)
tk.mainloop()
```

Expected is it should render an image from the URL and display on tkinter
NameError: name 'base64' is not defined

Comment: You need to import the base64 module.

Comment: I tried that but getting different error after each error solving

Comment: Well, then you need to fix each error. This specific question can only be solved by importing the module.

Comment: you should add url to this image so we could check what it is. Maybe it doesn't need `base64` but module `PIL`/`pillow`